# Set selectOneMenu with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to set my `selectOneMenu` with JQuery. I tried this way but it didn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
<p:selectOneMenu class="estado" id="estado" value="#{pessoaBean.pessoa.estado}" required="true" requiredMessage="O campo Estado é obrigatório.">
  <f:selectItems value="#{listaBean.estados}" var="estado" itemValue="#{estado}" itemLabel="#{estado.valor}" /> 
  <p:message for="estado"/>
</p:selectOneMenu> 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cep").change(function(){   
    var servico = "http://api.postmon.com.br/v1/cep/";
    var cep = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(servico + cep, function(data){
      $(".estado").val(data.estado);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I do not see any elements with the class you are trying to select: `$(".cep")`. This does not appear to be a valid selector, so the callback is never executed.

Comment: You may also have a Cross Site issue. You may want to see if that API is available via HTTPS and do some testing to ensure you're getting the proper results back.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the properly result of data.estado but I can't just set this in the selectOneMenu.

Comment: Ok, then can you provide an example of the data being returned? Any errors seen in Console?

Comment: No, any erros. When I put a console.log(data.resultado); I see the properly result, but the selectOneMenu doesn´t get the result.

Comment: I solved it using this: PF('estado').selectValue(data.estado); I created a widgetVar in my selectOneMenu. Thanks